# To show a function is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

For $\alpha>0$, consider $f\in L^1([\alpha,\infty))$ satisfying
$$\int_\alpha ^\infty   e^{-yt}e^{ixt}f(t)dt=0, \forall x\in\mathbb{R},y>0.   $$
Is it true that $f=0$ almost everywhere on $[\alpha,\infty)?$

My try:
$$\int_\alpha ^\infty   e^{izt}f(t)dt=0, \forall z\in\mathbb{H}.   $$
Also $\hat{f}=0\implies f=0.$ But $f\in L^1([\alpha,\infty))$ instead of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: You could easily extend $f$ to be defined on the entire real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(t)=f(t)e^{-t}$ for $t \geq \alpha$ and $0$ for $t <\alpha$. Then $g$ in integrable and its FT is $0$. Hence $g=0$ a.e and this implies $f=0$ a.e. on $[\alpha , \infty)$